# Bibliographic software (like EndNote) on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, virtualization, desktop-apps

I've been having terrible luck finding bibliographic software such as Endnote for Ubuntu. It feels like the only solution is to install VirtualMachine with Windows installed. But it would be horrible to have to switch to VirtualMachine every time I need to do text processing, as all my relevant analysis scripts, analysis output, my article folder, etc are on the Linux end of the machine.

Anybody have a solution either in the form of software directly available to Linux or a efficient set-up of Endnote through VirtualMachine?

Comment: [mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) has a linux desktop client. Maybe this would be an alternative for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=835) Endnote is supported by wine so you can run it on Ubuntu using Wine.

You can also look at some free alternative like [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Latex + (BibTex | BibLatex)

You can also use Libreoffice + (Zotero | bibtex | ReferenceManager | Mendley, even Endnote)  See details in [bibliography references for libreoffice](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Referencing_Systems_in_LibreOffice)

Comment: I will take a look at it, but for now, running through Wine might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A valuable alternative over the past years has been [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/), a reference manager that specializes on BibTeX. The data is actually stored as flat BibTeX files, which makes switching to JabRef in running projects pretty straightforward.

Until now, the software is actively developed and has seen significant functional improvements and bug fixing over the years.